# path.join doesn't run with list

Tags: python, image, list, path

I have an error when I want to get image path in my folder..

> path = os.fspath(path)
>
> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

And this is my code:

```
root_dir = './test/' 
#######################Enumerate classes###################################
class_folders_train = glob.glob(os.path.join(root_dir, '*'))
print("class_folders_train :",class_folders_train)

train_paths = []
    for idx, class_folder in enumerate(class_folders_train):
        print("ok")
        image_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(class_folders_train, '*.tif'))
        print("image_paths :",image_paths)
        train_paths.extend([(im_path, idx) for im_path in image_paths])
    print("train_paths :",train_paths)
```

So my code dies just after print("ok")...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> image_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(class_folders_train, '*.tif'))
> ```

You probably mean `class_folder` here, not `class_folders_train`.